# How to delete a data extension (entire DE not only records) using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I was trying to delete a data extension inside automation but couldn't find way to delete it using SSJS.

This is data on how to delete records in a data extension, but not the data extension itself: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionDeleteData.html

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by using [WSProxy](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/introducing-wsproxy-salesforce-marketing-cloud-eliot-harper):

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
    
    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    
    try {
    
        var dataExtensionName = "Customers";

        var req = api.retrieve("DataExtension", ["CustomerKey"], {
            Property: "Name",
            SimpleOperator: "equals",
            Value: dataExtensionName
        });

        var customerKey = req.Results[0].CustomerKey;

        var req = api.retrieve("DataExtension", ["ObjectID"], {
    Property: "DataExtension.CustomerKey",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: customerKey
});

var objectId = req.Results[0].ObjectID;

var result = api.deleteItem("DataExtension", { "ObjectID": objectId });

        Write(Stringify(result));
        
    } catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }   
</script>
```

Make sure to change the value of the `dataExtensionName` variable to match your specific DE.

The above code snippet comes from Ivan Razine’s article available here: https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-use-wsproxy-to-work-with-data-extensions-in-ssjs/, which also covers other operations on Data Extensions via WSProxy.